# Making post request from redirection in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, httpresponse

I am trying to redirect to another URL from node js by using response.writeHead method

```
response.writeHead(301, {Location : <redirecturl>})
```

I need to have this redirection is being executed by POST method, however it is always executed by GET. What is the way that the redirection can be made as a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A redirect by default sends a GET request. According to the HTTP spec, a 301 redirection means sending a GET request. If you want to redirect with the same method (POST), you can try doing a 307 redirect instead.

Comment: Thanks .. I just got it with 307. Any how i need to check for any other concequences using 307.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between redirection in both GET and POST methods. Both method should work find. Better you can your expressjs framework in which it is

```
 res.redirect('http://example.com');
```

Be careful, when using status code `301` which means Moved Perman­ently. Once browser gets `301` status code, it will directly try the redirected URL from the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, I believe this is what you are describing:
The client has made a request to your application using an HTTP method (get, post, etc.)   You are responding to that request by sending back a 301 error and a new URL (redirecturl)
The client then decides to implement a get request for the redirecturl.

You can't change how a client responds to a 301.  That is out of your control and it is normal for browsers to initiate a get for the redirecturl.

You could initiate a post request from your server to the redirecturl.
You could send back a webpage which would then submit a post request from the client.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am doing this on a node js app. And yes, the problem statement is what you have mentioned and i have to redirect the url from my node js application to specified URL